# Range based for loops and eliminating runtime errors

Tags: runtime-error, programming-languages

Is there a reason a language must have traditional for loops and array indexing, or is it possible for a language to replace both of those things with just a range based for loop? If they were replaced and you had an optional null type that could only be used if it pointed to something valid could you eliminate all runtime errors(excluding running out of memory)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question.  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Can you elaborate? IIRC Swift removed the C-style `for` loop recently, but of course all loops can be implemented as `while` loops eventually. You could eliminate array overrun errors that way, but there are many more runtime errors than running out of memory (what about user-entered data?). Would help to know what kinds of programs you're talking about and why you think they would be unable to encounter runtime errors?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason a language must have for loops at all, may they be traditional or not. For example, Haskell neither has loops nor statements at all.